# Estou a receber pontos de outros utilizadores

Tags: bug, suporte, status-intencional

Estou a receber pontos de tópicos que não participei em nenhum momento.

Recebi pontos por este tópico: [tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10909/por-que-multiplicacao-e-mais-rapido-que-divisao/10911#10911)

A única ligação com o tópico é o nome, o utilizador que deveria receber os pontos também chama-se Filipe.

Comment: Acho que deveria adicionar uma tag como bug.

Comment: @EMBarbosa adicionado.

Comment: pq voce afirma que está recebendo pontos desse tópico? na sua aba "reputação" não tem nada que link a ele

Comment: Pode ser um bug apenas no mecanismo que notifica o ganho de pontos, pois como disse o @Math na aba "reputação" do seu perfil esse post não aparece.

Comment: Você conseguiria um printscreen que demonstre? Fica mais simples saber exatamente onde está o problema (especialmente para os devs).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal já percebi o problema, alterei o voto que passou de negativo para positivo e recebi pontos por isso. Já não me lembrava que tinha interagido com o tópico, não encontrava uma resposta, por isso abri o tópico, estava mesmo convencido de que não tinha dado o voto.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada pois foi criada por um equívoco do autor.

Comment: Você ganhou pontos por essa e outras perguntas minhas quando seus votos negativos em série nas minhas respostas foram revertidos.

Comment: Estou votando para reabrir. Quando votei para fechar eu tinha entendido que o autor da pergunta havia retirado o voto negativo e tinha recebido ponto por isso, o que na minha opinião não justificava o tópico. Entretanto não foi isso que realmente aconteceu, na verdade ele recebeu vários pontos de uma só vez, todos eles linkados a publicações do @Filipe.Fonseca, a origem desses pontos entretanto foi a reversão de votos negativos em série aplicados pelo autor da pergunta, logo, na minha opinião o tópico pode ser pertinente e deve ser reaberto.

Answer (score 5):

Conforme dito, você não recebeu reputação por votos em post dos outros, mas sim porque seus votos contra foram revertidos.
A confusão vem por que ao mesmo tempo em que a pergunta "ganha" mais um voto, você recebe de volta o ponto que gastou para votar contra.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já havia percebido isso e apaguei a pergunta uma vez que não era um erro e sim um mal entendido. Se apaguei a pergunta, porque ainda existe?

Comment: A pergunta possivelmente foi restaurada pelo @Gabe para que outros utilizadores que tiverem a mesma dúvida que você teve possam ser respondidos por esta questão. Obter sua resposta e excluir a pergunta impede que outras pessoas tirem suas dúvidas e fere o conceito do SO como um todo.

Comment: @Filipe Exatamente o que o Filipe.Fonseca disse. Sua pergunta pode ter nascido de um mal entendido, mas é uma situação que pode se repetir com outros usuários e por isso ela tem valor aqui no Meta.

Comment: Ok percebi, realmente pode ajudar alguém.