# Encerrando descontextualização razão está em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Faltou traduzir o conteúdo no Meta, como pode ser visto nesta pergunta: [Estou a receber pontos de outros utilizadores](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1238/estou-a-receber-pontos-de-outros-utilizadores)

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow em Português ou a plataforma da rede Stack Exchange, within the scope defined in the central de ajuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traduzido para:

> Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre o Stack Overflow em Português ou a plataforma da rede Stack Exchange, conforme definido na central de ajuda.